# What are different ways to pass URL in Ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, load, partial-views

I am using Ajax to pass data to partial view with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#Request_For_Id').change(function () {
            var mdlno = document.getElementById("Request_For_Id").value;


            $.ajax({
                url: '/Search/MDLNoDataList/',

                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    id: mdlno
                },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#viewlist").html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("No Records Found");
                    //$("#viewlist").html('No Records Found');
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Can I use `Html.RenderPartial` or `Html.RenderAction` etc to load partial view?

```
 url: '/Search/MDLNoDataList/',
```

Is there any other way than this?

Comment: You can use those. but then it is not ajax.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I am just asking can I write like this ?  url: '<%: Html.Partial("MDLNoDataList") %>' ????

Comment: Never doubt, you can't!

Answer (score 0):

```
url: '/Search/MDLNoDataList/',
```

**is there any other way than this ? Yes**

Url.Content is used when you wish to resolve a url and pass it as the relative path:

```
url: '@Url.Content("/Search/MDLNoDataList/")',
```

Url.Action is used to resolve an action from a controller such as:

```
url: '@Url.Action("MDLNoDataList", "Search")',
```

**Can I use Html.RenderPartial or Html. RenderAction etc to load partial view?**

*You can use this to load partial view, with out affecting whole view, [check this](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/) to know the differences*

Comment: Edited my answer to include single quotes-check now.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your controller action return the partial view:

```
public ActionResult MDLNoDataList(string id)
{
    ...
    return PartialView();
}
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Request_For_Id').change(function () {
            var mdlno = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                // If you are using the WebForms view engine you should use:
                // url: '<%= Url.Action("MDLNoDataList", "Search") %>'
                url: '@Url.Action("MDLNoDataList", "Search")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: mdlno
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#viewlist').html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('No Records Found');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```